# Invite system in an iPhone game

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an iPhone game, using the Facebook SDK.
I want to be able to post on a friend's wall an invitation with a link to the game (App Store link).
I looked everywhere but couldn't find a way to do it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Facebook's Requests system - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Answer (score -2):

First you must set the permissions-

```
'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,user_likes'
```

then,

```
$attachment = array
(
     'access_token'=>  $accessToken,
     'message' => 'Дадох прогноза в Лаком за гол!',
     'name' => 'Лаком за гол',
     'description' => $fname.' участва в играта на Actualno.com. Участвай и ти и го победи!',
     'link' => 'http://www.actualno.com/'.$this->appname.'/game?app_data='.$uid,
     'picture' => 'http://www.actualno.com/img/'.$this->appname.'/'.$this->appname.'_post.jpg'
);
$facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

Comment: This will post on my wall - I want to post on a friend's wall